# Smallest square-closed set containing $A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let us call a subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}$ *square-closed* if for all $x\in X$, $x^2\in X$.

> **Proposition.** Any subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is contained in smallest square-closed set. Prove the proposition.

**My question is**: Let $A=\left\{2\right\}$ So $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ but it is not square-closed set because $4\not\in A$. But the prposition says that any subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is contained in smallest square-closed set. I probably didn't understand the proposition, can you help, can you explain?

Comment: You need to show that for any $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ there is a set $B\subseteq \mathbb R$ such that (1) $A\subseteq B$, (2) $B$ is square-closed and, (3) *if* $C\subseteq\mathbb R$ is square-closed and $A\subseteq C$, *then* $B\subseteq C$.

Comment: There are many different square-closed sets which contain $A$. The proposition says that there is one which is indisputably the _smallest_.

Comment: In the example you gave of $A=\{2\}$, the set $B$ is $\{2,4,16,256,65536,\dots\}$.

Comment: Thanks for comments

Answer (score 2):

As Andrés E. Caicedo suggests, what it means by "smallest" square-closed set is a bit weird. You are supposed to show that $A$ is contained in a smallest square-closed set $B$. What it means by "smallest" is that all square-closed sets containing $A$ also contain $B$.

Andrés' comment defines this formally. What you have to show is:

> For any set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, there is a set $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, such that: (1) $A \subseteq B$, (2) $B$ is square-closed, and (3) for any $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, if $C$ is square-closed and $A \subseteq C$, then $B \subseteq C$.

A good idea to start out with the proof is to define $B$ as follows: "Let $B$ be the intersection of all square-closed sets containing $A$."

Using the intersection of all the sets is, in general, a good trick to try if you ever have to prove the existence of a "smallest" set.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: @KathySong You are welcome.